# Restart R within Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to call a simple python script from within R using system2(). I've read some information I found vague that said if 'too much' memory is used, it won't work.

If I load a large dataset and use some information in it to use as arguments to pass into system2(), it will only work if I manually click "Restart R" in call Rstudio.

What I want:

```
df <- read.csv('some_large_file.csv')
###extracting some info called 'args_vec'
for(arg in args_vec){
    system2('python', args)
}
```

This won't work as is. The for loop is simply passed over.

What I need:

```
df <- read.csv('some_large_file.csv')
###extracting some info called 'args_vec'
###something that 'restarts' R
for(arg in args_vec){
    system2('python', args)
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r) doesn't quite get what I want. Namely, it doesn't work for me within Rstudio and it calls "system" (which presents the same problem as "system2" in this case). In fact, when I put the answer referenced above in my Rprofile.site file, it just immediately closed rstudio:

I tried the suggestion as a normal function (rather than using "makeActiveBinding", and it didn't quite work.

```
##restart R in r session  -- doesn't work
makeActiveBinding("refresh", function() { system("R --save"); q("no") }, .GlobalEnv)

##nor did this:
refresh <- function() { system("R --save"); q("no") }
```

I tried a number of variations of these two options above, but this is getting long for what feels like a simple question. There's a lot I don't yet understand about the startup process and "makeActiveBinding" is a bit mysterious. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to restart the whole R? If you use `rm(list=ls())` which cleans the workspace, and maybe manual garbage collection with `gc()` just in case, that should be enough?

Comment: @BenHunter it's immediately closing RStudio because you're calling `q` after restarting. Take out the call to `q` and it should do exactly the same thing as selecting Restart R in RStudio.

Comment: @Hemmo, I know that's an option, and in this case it might be a good choice, but I'd really like to know how to solve this, as is, without losing my workspace (or saving, removing, and then reloading it).

Comment: @Matthew Plourde, that almost works, but Rstudio just reloads and doesn't give me a prompt. Specifically, all startup activity runs again, I can see packages from my Rprofile get loaded, but I don't see a ">" prompt.

Comment: @BenHunter, funny, I do get a prompt. Are you using the active binding or the function way? As a side note, using an active binding in this situation is playing with fire and unnecessary---I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, just the function. Good to know about makeActiveBinding. But Rstudio just clams up when I call refresh(). I get the stop sign in the interpreter. I'm just letting it sit there for a while now, but it doesn't look like it's going to do anything. My Rprofile.site file is /usr/lib/R/etc. I'm going to try it on my machine at home and see how it works. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If it doesn't seem to give you a prompt, try whacking Enter one time to see if it's just not being displayed.

Answer (score 93):

In Rstudio, you can restart the R session by:

```
command/ctrl + shift + F10
```

You can also use:

```
.rs.restartR()
```

Comment: this does not answer the question since it seems they want a command line

Answer (score 16):

RStudio has this undocumented `rs.restartR()` which is supposed to do just that: restarting R.

However, it does not unload the packages that were loaded, nor does it clean the environment, so that I have some doubts about if it restarts R at all.

Comment: It does free up whatever memory used to be used up and was later released though... so it does do something (very useful in some cases).

Comment: Indeed very useful for my use-case: I regularly read in a password-protected excel file on a shared drive using read.xlsx, which makes the excel file become read-only. I can then run the above line which prevents this consequence of read-only. Thus other members of my team can happily save any edits that are not important to my work.

Answer (score 3):

If you use RStudio, use the menu item Session > Restart R or the associated keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+F10` (Windows and Linux) or `Command+Shift+F10` (Mac OS). Additional keyboard shortcuts make it easy to restart development where you left off, i.e. to say “re-run all the code up to HERE”:

In an R script, use `Ctrl+Alt+B` (Windows and Linux) or `Command+Option+B` (Mac OS)
In R markdown, use `Ctrl+Alt+P` (Windows and Linux) or `Command+Option+P` (Mac OS)
If you run R from the shell, use `Ctrl+D` or `q()` to quit, then restart R.

Answer (score 2):

For those not limited to a command that want something that actually resets the system (no prior state, no loaded packages, no variables, etc.) you can select `Terminate R` from the `Session` menu.

It is a bit awkward (asks you if you are sure). If anyone knows something like `clear all` or really `clear classes` in MATLAB let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried embedding the function call within the apply function, rather than a for loop?

I've had some pieces of code that ran the system out of memory in a for loop run perfectly with apply. It might help?