# Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token error in cloud speech API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-speech-api

I have followed the Google cloud speech API quickstart of requesting API by using

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
     https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize \
     -d @sync-request.json
```

and following  [link](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/quickstart) but I got error of

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It could be that *The Application Default Credentials are not available*

Try to login by running

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

And follow the instructions, reference: [gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login)

If you want to make sure the authentication process went well, run:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

You should see an access token, reference [gcloud auth application-default print-access-token](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token)

Comment: hi i have implemented google cloud vision api and followed this link https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/how-to upto OCR .API works fine but i want to implement cloud speech api as well . that can return real time audio streaming results in json format...but i am new to GCP.. I AM afraid ..if i set up cloud speech api then does it affect previous vision OCR setup ?

Comment: It should not affect if you are using the same account for both APIs.

Comment: Basically what `gcloud auth application-default login` does is acquiring credentials to make it available to the applications in your local machine to use when they are configured to use **Application Default Credentials**

Comment: What package/language you use for your OCR setup?

Comment: You can use a service account as explained in the [Vision API docs for Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication).

Comment: thank you now i can access cloud firestore via rest

Answer (score 17):

I fixed the problem by logging out, and logging in to agree to some new terms and conditions google have made since last time I used google clouds (firebase in my case).

Comment: you mean console logout ?

Comment: I got the error code using firebase in terminal. I logout from firebase through terminal:
firebase logout
and then
firebase login

Answer (score 9):

Replace `$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)` with what gets printed when you call the command.

Comment: That worked painlessly for me.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your date and time are correct and also your timezone is correct.
This was how I solved this problem

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue in my case.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. Its quite a tricky one to catch. Indeed a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

[Samir's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734637/5783745) solution worked for me.

Just a reminder that if using other software interacting with GCP, you may have to **restart software before the auth takes effect**.

In my case, when using RStudio, I ran `gcloud auth application-default login` to authenticate, then [command + shift + f10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25747753/5783745) to restart the R session, and *then* everything was good to go.

Some packages will have a function that refreshes the token in the current R session. For example the bigrquery library has `bq_auth()` which adds the new token to the R session (without needing to restart the session etc)

Comment: I ran `gcloud auth application-default login` in terminal and got `bash: gcloud: command not found`. Do I have to install something first?

Comment: @SweepyDodo yes, you need to install gcloud first

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility that you have disabled auth. So

`gcloud config set auth/disable_credentials false`

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the scopes assigned to the credentials since the last time you signed-in your client, make sure you sign in again to update the client tokens.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when using GCP CLI, so unrelated but maybe someone stumbles on this thread same as me.

I ran this command:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

after that, the error was still there, but then I ran second command

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

CLI then prompted me to provide password, I did, and after that I was able to use GCP CLI again (I didn't use access token that was returned, simply re-entering password worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

I recently have this error with my Spring boot Application. Because of the accessToken need to be refresh/renew (may be renew the time expireTime milisecond too)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).