# How we can create dataproc cluster using http request, getting error Expected OAuth 2 access token,

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new in Python and airflow. I want to create a dataproc cluster using an http request  inside a pythonoperator task. See the below code:

```
def create_cluster():

    API_ENDPOINT = "https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/trim 
-**********/regions/us-central1-b/clusters"
    data = {
        "projectId": "trim-**********",
        "clusterName": "cluster-1",
        "config": {
            "configBucket": "",
            "gceClusterConfig": {
                "subnetworkUri": "default",
                "zoneUri": "us-central1-b"
            },
            "masterConfig": {
                "numInstances": 1,
                "machineTypeUri": "n1-standard-1",
                "diskConfig": {
                "bootDiskSizeGb": 500,
                "numLocalSsds": 0
            }
        },
        "workerConfig": {
            "numInstances": 2,
            "machineTypeUri": "n1-standard-1",
            "diskConfig": {
                "bootDiskSizeGb": 100,
                "numLocalSsds": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
r = requests.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, data=data)
pastebin_url = r.text
print("The pastebin URL is:%s" % pastebin_url)
```

But I am getting an error: `Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.` See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

What would be the solution for this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For this error "Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.". I found one solution in this stackoverflow link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720306/request-had-invalid-authentication-credentials-expected-oauth-2-access-token-er  .I executed both command and able to see access token after that I received email as well from google "Google Auth Library was granted access to your Google account". But still I am getting same error after hitting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/trim 
-**********/regions/us-central1-b/clusters