# .Last() in .RProfile doesn't execute

Tags: r

I'm trying to make R restart on quit, so I'm using .Last in my .Rprofile.
Solution modified from [Quit and restart a clean R session from within R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r), and I've tried the other solutions in that answer to no avail.
my .First() works fine, but when I q() at the end, it prompts for "save workspace image?" and after answering, it insta-closes

```
.Last <- function()
{
 print("new R in 3 seconds")
Sys.sleep(3)
 system("R --no-save")
 print("close R in 3 seconds")
 Sys.sleep(3)
}
print("test")
```

(the print at the end is because there's a hidden "feature" where .Rprofile ignores the last line if theres no newline, I know it shouldn't execute that.)

Comment: The code you have posted comes from some comments below that post but the actual solution in that post works for me.

Comment: yeah, my comment below *that* comment was actually in reference to the original solution, which I tested and also did not work. "refresh" just closes R. When you tested it, did you have a ".First" function also in your Rprofile?

Comment: The solution works for me.  My .Rprofile only sets a few options.

Comment: ah. I ran shell("RGui") by itself and the answer became obvious...

      shell(paste0(R.home(),"/bin/i386/RGui"))
works. I had setwd() earlier away from the default. I still don't get why ".Last" isn't executing though, isn't RProfile loaded in its entirety when R opens? the system("R") would need the same adjustment, of course, but Sys.sleep(3) wasn't executing either

Comment: For most people `Rgui.exe` is on their path so there is no need to specify the path.  If you prefer not to do that then this should work: `shell(file.path(R.home("bin"), "Rgui.exe"))`

Comment: I'm running this from "R.exe" instead of "Rgui", so that works but it just spawns a "child process" of Rgui. from that child process, I can call refresh and it refreshes the way I want it to. However, the original R.exe is just sitting there while all this is happening...

Comment: See https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4056