# Using cat() to send keystrokes to console

Tags: r

so we can use `cat("\f")` or `cat("\014")` to send <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to the console. I was wondering what do `"\f"` and `"\014"` represent. I would like to use `cat()` to send other keystrokes to the console, such as <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F10</kbd>.

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really "sending keystrokes to a console" by using `cat`. You are sending character representations of them (if they exist) in most cases. Refer to the help page `?Quotes` to see which escaped characters have valid representations. I'm guessing you want to send commands to your system and there are functions that allow communication with the OS: `?system` and on windows `?shell` is also sometimes needed.