# Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database

Tags: r, roxygen2

I don't know what is going on, everything was working great but suddenly I started to have this error message on the documentation:

> Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database '......descopl.rdb' is
>   corrupt

I removed almost all my code and build again then publish to Github, but when I use the other laptop to download the package, the package is being downloaded and loaded but I can't call any of the functions, and the documentation states that error.

I don't know what caused the problem, I am using roxygen to generate the documentation.

https://github.com/WilliamKinaan/descopl

Comment: you could give a link to the repo. and exactly how you created the rdb

Comment: @rawr here you go https://github.com/WilliamKinaan/descopl

Comment: I don't see major things wrong with your r package. I'm not sure why you have two scripts with copies of the same functions -- just keep the one with the roxygen docs. `preprocessing` should not be at top-level, move it to `inst/preprocessing`. And you should delete the read-and-delete-me file. Otherwise, it just seems like your .rdb is corrupt.. like the error says. Plus you didn't specify how you created it

Answer (score 154):

It seems that the error arises when the package cannot be decompressed by R (as @rawr established, it is corrupt). This solutions have worked for me:

1) Check for possible errors in the creation of the `.Rdb`  files

2) Try [restarting your R session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r) (e.g. `.rs.restartR()` if in RStudio)

3) The package might have been installed in your computer (even though it does not work). Remove it using `?remove.packages()`

Comment: my site restarted and `devtools::install_github('WilliamKinaan/descopl')` is working fine.

Comment: In RStudio you can restart R with `.rs.restartR()` which will restore your session (variables, libraries) but fixes the `.rdb' is corrupt` issue.

Comment: thank you,this worked for me while using magick library!

Answer (score 8):

I have had this problem with `roxygen2` as well. Couldn't see any problem with any of my functions. In the end deleting the `.rdb` file and then getting roxygen2 to rebuild it seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I think the explanation for what is causing this is [here.](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/pull/1001)
It's related to devtools.
Per @Zfunk

```
cd ~/Rlibs/descopl/help
rm *.rdb
```

Restart R. Look at the help for the package again. Fixed!

Answer (score 6):

I received this error after re-installing a library whilst another R session was running.

Simply restarting the existing R session(s) solved for me (i.e. running `.rs.restartR()` to restart the sessions)

Answer (score 5):

Basically all answers require restarting R to resolve the issue, but I found myself in an environment where I really didn't want to restart R.

I am posting here a somewhat hack-ish solution suggested by Jim Hester in a [bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16644) about the lazy-load corruption issue.

The gist of it is that the package may have some vestigial S3 methods listed in session's `.__S3MethodsTable__.` environment. I don't have a very systematic way of identifying which S3 methods in that environment come from where, but I think a good place to start is the `print` methods, and looking for `S3method` registrations in the package's `NAMESPACE`.

You can then remove those S3 methods from the `.__S3MethodsTable__.` environment and try again, e.g.

```
rm(list="print.object", envir = get(".__S3MethodsTable__.", envir = baseenv()))
```

You may also need to unload some DLLs if some new messages come up like

> no such symbol glue_ in package /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/glue/libs/glue.so

You can check `getLoadedDLLs()` to see which such files are loaded in your session. In the case of `glue` here, the following resolved the issue:

```
library.dynam.unload('glue', '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/glue')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using R-studio:
1) ctrl+shift+f10 to restart r session
2) tools -> Check for package updates -> update all packages
3) library(ggmap)

Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on RStudio on mac OS - updating all the packages and restarting r session did the trick.