# ggplot2 fails to load

Tags: r, ggplot2, load

ggplot fails to load.  I uninstalled ggplot2 and reinstalled.  Then uninstalled ggplot2 again, uninstalled R 3.2.2, reinstalled R 3.2.2, reinstalled ggplot2.  Same errors.  scales.rdb corrupted, internal error -3.

This is the first time I attempted to use ggplot2 with Windows 10 OS.  Error message + sessionInfo below.  I see that the sessionInfo has R running under Windows 8, but Windows 10 is installed.  I don't know if that is meaningful.

Any feedback is appreciated.

**I figured it out.  the scales.rdb file was corrupted.  re-installing scales  as install.packages("scales") did not work.  install.packages("scales", dependencies = TRUE) did work.**

```
> library(ggplot2)
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/sbmack/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/scales/R/scales.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tidyr_0.3.1 dplyr_0.4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1      digest_0.6.8     assertthat_0.1   grid_3.2.2       plyr_1.8.3       R6_2.1.1         gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1       
 [9] magrittr_1.5     stringi_1.0-1    reshape2_1.4.1   proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.2      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.2.2  
[17] colorspace_1.2-6
```

Comment: Reinstall package scales?

Comment: reinstalling doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my R studio This worked for me--

1. Tools->Check for Package updates-->select all and update
2. Restart R session with .rs.restartR()
3. install ggplot2 again and problem solved!

For a more detailed discussion and other solutions, please refer to this thread--[Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424608/error-in-fetchkey-lazy-load-database)