# Check for or remove corrupt R packages or corrupt databases

Tags: r, package, corrupt

I am not sure if I have a corrupt R database or corrupt R packages.  I installed several packages in R a week ago and, ever since then, my previously installed packages have not been working correctly.

When I try to reinstall a previously working package, I see:

```
lazy-load database 'C:/Users/Jennifer/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/gstudio/R/gstudio.rdb' is corrupt
```

How do I fix/remove corrupt R databases or corrupt packages?

Comment: You can remove with `remove.packages()` if you know what's causing the problem. Otherwise, it might be worth it to make a list of all your packages with `rownames(installed.packages())`, blow everything away, and start over.

Comment: Seems I needed to restart R! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593159/failing-to-load-the-new-ggplot2-in-r