# Corruption error in R? - "Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library/ROSE/help/ROSE.rdb' is corrupt"

Tags: r, package, corrupt

Should I proceed with my programming if I am getting this error? - "Error in fetch(key) :  lazy-load database 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library/ROSE/help/ROSE.rdb' is corrupt"

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which package? What code did you run? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and edit your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424608/error-in-fetchkey-lazy-load-database)

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution for this problem is to restart your Rstudio, as J.J. Allaire (founder of Rstudio) suggested [here](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/298#issuecomment-368258575).