# How can I plotly a ggplot treemap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, treemap, r-plotly

I am looking to get this gradient colors on the map:

```
ramp <- colorRamp(c("royalblue4", "white"))
ramp.list <- rgb( ramp(seq(0, 1, length = 15)), max = 255)
```

But also, and more important, I am looking to add plotly charactheristics to the graph (specially hovering text output). This is my data:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("Apple", "Avocado", "Banana", 
"Carrot", "Mango", "Mushroom", "Onion", "Orange", "Pineapple", 
"Strawberry", "Sweet-lemon", "Watermelon", "Wildberry"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 
    7L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("23", "24", "36", "42", "43", "46", 
    "48", "52", "56", "61", "82", "94"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

And this is what I've tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ramp <- colorRamp(c("royalblue4", "white"))
ramp.list <- rgb( ramp(seq(0, 1, length = 15)), max = 255)
g <- ggplot(dtd7, aes(area = n, fill = topic, label = as.character(topic))) +
  geom_treemap()+
  geom_treemap_text(fontface = "italic", colour = "white", place = "centre")  +
  theme(legend.position = "none") 

ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: There is no support for treemaps in R's plotly api yet. Please see https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1654

Comment: I saw that, but thought that 10 weeks would've been enough time and it was done already. Thanks!

Comment: They will close the issue when they are done.

Comment: Treemap traces are now available in the dev version: `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`. To test them just copy a [sunburst example](https://plot.ly/r/sunburst-charts/) and replace `type = 'sunburst'` with `type = 'treemap'`.

Comment: What's going on when it drops this out: `* DONE (plotly)
Error in fetch(key) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/Melania Castillo Bra/Documents/R/R-3.6.2/library/plotly/help/plotly.rdb' is corrupt`?

Comment: I don't know. You might want to reinstall the package.

Comment: Already did and it keeps on not showing 'treemap' as an available option, too bad! :(

Comment: Plus that corruption thing is not allowing help to give out any info relating plotly!

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424608/error-in-fetchkey-lazy-load-database).

Comment: `plot_ly(dtd7, ids = ~topic, values = ~n, parents = ~topic,
            type = 'treemap')` using this but getting a blank output, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using treemap traces you can display hierarchical datasets.

Accordingly the problem with your code snippet from the comments `plot_ly(dtd7, ids = ~topic, values = ~n, parents = ~topic, type = 'treemap')` is, that you are assigning the same data to `ids` and `parents`.

Please check the following:

```
library(plotly)

dtd7 <- structure(
  list(
    topic = structure(
      c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L,
        5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L),
      .Label = c("Apple", "Avocado", "Banana", "Carrot", "Mango","Mushroom", "Onion", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Strawberry", "Sweet-lemon", "Watermelon", "Wildberry"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    n = structure(
      c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L,
        7L, 8L, 1L),
      .Label = c("23", "24", "36", "42", "43", "46", "48", "52", "56", "61", "82", "94"),
      class = "factor"
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-13L)
)

p <- plot_ly(
  dtd7,
  labels = ~ topic,
  parents = NA,
  values = ~ n,
  type = 'treemap',
  hovertemplate = "Ingredient: %{label}<br>Count: %{value}<extra></extra>"
)

p
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Worked out perfectly fine, thanks! Would you happen to know how can I edit the hovering pop up to: Ingredient: ~topic, Count = ~n? Tried using `add_trace` but I can't fully figure how I can do this without knowing any JavaScript, sorry.

Comment: I just updated the answer. You should try running `schema()` and navigate: object ► traces ► treemap ► attributes ► hovertemplate - for further information.

Comment: Wonderful, really appreciate it!

Comment: Hello again - Could you please advice me on a way to show count below teach group name without the nned of hovering on it?

Comment: Sure :) - I just left an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63903111/add-count-below-name-in/) - cheers