# R CTRL+SHIFT+F10 use from command line

Tags: r, rstudio, restart

I looking for command/script equal to shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+F10 (which means restart) in Rstudio. I need to do this because of conflicts/cache's in few packages. I can't lose variable I made earlier.

PS: rm(ls() ) is not a solution!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quit and restart a clean R session from within R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r)

Comment: I hope the following link helps solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872029/why-doesnt-restarting-r-with-ctrl-shift-f10-clear-my-environment-variables

Answer (score 2):

You can use .rs.restartR() to restart R session