# Why doesn't restarting R with Ctrl-Shift-F10 clear my environment variables?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have RStudio working on two different machines:  mine and a colleague's.

When I restart R in RStudio with the `Ctrl-Shift-F10` shortcut, all my global environment variables go away.  Not so for my colleague's, who frequently puts `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))` in our shared code.

Is there an optional parameter somewhere, so that restarting R always clears environment variables?

Comment: Yes, perhaps it is the "Restore .RData into workspace at startup" option in the RStudio general options?

Comment: @be_green Neither of us has that box ticked, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: Did you read something that said that restarting it in that way should / shouldn't delete the environment variables, or is this just something you discovered? More importantly, have you compared your `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` (yours vs your co-workers')?

Comment: Is there an attribute in those files which determines whether global environment variables get cleared?

Comment: Try setting the option 'Save workspace to .RData on exit' to Never? I don't have the 'Restore .RData into workspace at startup' option ticked either, but it makes the difference for me. Never = cleared environment, Ask = uncleared environment.

Comment: @Z.Lin That's very counterintuitive:  it feels like that shouldn't work.  But it does!  Please rewrite your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Disclaimer: this has 100% effectiveness based on a sample size of 5 so far (validated by OP & Badger), but I'm recording it for posterity since other forums where I've seen similar questions ([example 1](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200729433-Restarting-R-session-in-RStudio-doesn-t-clear-the-workspace), [example 2](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200921317-Session-Restart-R-restores-the-environment)) don't even have that. :)*

**Solution**: Go to Tools / Global Options / General & change the "Save workspace to .RData on exit" dropdown option to "Never".

Possible interpretation: Even if you chose the 'Ask' option in "Save workspace to .RData on exit", Ctrl-Shift-F10 shortcut won't ask before the session gets restarted. But unless you explicitly chose to NEVER save workspace on exit, RStudio will keep it somewhere just in case. (I'm not sure where, though. There's no .RData file in my working directory corresponding to the restored environment...)

Comment: Your sample size is now 3:  it works for both my colleague and me.  I also struggled to find a satisfying answer by googling, so hopefully this post will help future users :)

Comment: Having done this recently on a pair of machines, bump that to 5.

Comment: Links are broken for (example 1, example 2)