# Clearing the workspace and plots in all graphical devices at once

Tags: r

The command `rm(list=ls())` is used clear the `R` workspace (i.e. clear all the objects shown by `ls()`). To clear the console, I personally do like pressing `CTRL + L` but you can alternatively use `cat("\014")`. To clear all the plots, you can use `dev.off()`. However, this doesn't clear a 3D plot in RGL devices opened in `XQuartz` on Mac. My questions are:

1. Is there a single command to clear the workspace and all the plots at the same time?
2. Any command to remove all the plots irrespective of the graphical device that we use

Any pointers to get around this are appreciated.

Comment: `?dev.off` -> `graphics.off()`.

Comment: @Gregor, yeah sure I know but i wanted to avoid using the GUI and that's why.

Comment: If that's the case, then [duplicate here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6313079/903061). I think the only difference is you haven't mentioned unloading packages. Restarting R will obviously not have any packages loaded beyond the defaults, whereas your question seems to want everything cleared up *except* packages.

Comment: With no clarification about differences from the suggested dupe, I'm voting to close. Happy to re-open if the answers there aren't satisfactory.

Comment: @Gregor, I already have seen that buddy and voting to close a question is not fair.

Comment: As I said, I'm happy to re-open if you edit your question explain why the answers there don't work for you.

Comment: G. Grothendieck's answer looks very applicable, as do Adam Perelman's two answers.

Comment: @Gregor, I tried it but that doesn't work for ALL graphical devices (for example RGL devices as I stated in my question). I

Comment: Strange, `.rs.restartR()` closes RGL devices for me as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33102389/903061): e.g. `rgl::plot3d(1, 1, 1); .rs.restartR()`. My RGL windows is closed. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33738713/903061) combines `.rs.restartR()` with `cat("\014")` to also clear the console. Does this not work for you?

Comment: @Gregor, it is strange indeed buddy. It is OK and yeah  will manually clear them all.