# Quantstrat Problem: "Transactions must be added in order", Despite Bug Fix

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm trying to use Brian Peterson's [code](https://rdrr.io/rforge/quantstrat/src/demo/macd.R) to learn applications of MACD for our investment management situation, but have run into this error:

> "Error in addTxn(Portfolio = portfolio, Symbol = symbol, TxnDate = txntime,  : 
>   Transactions must be added in order. TxnDate (2007-01-03) is before last transaction in portfolio (2014-04-29) for AAPL"

I see [here](https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat/issues/57) that this was a bug for which Josh Ulrich pushed a fix last May (2017), so why am I still getting it, especially when I am using posted code by a `quantstrat` author?
I tried another fix Brian suggested [here](https://github.com/braverock/blotter/issues/51), but that didn't help.

The problem occurs with the `applyStrategy` call (about line 109 in Brian's code):

```
 out<-applyStrategy(strat.st , portfolios=portfolio.st,
               parameters=list(nFast=fastMA, nSlow=slowMA,
               nSig=signalMA,maType=maType),verbose=TRUE)
```

I realize `quantstrat` is "still in heavy development", so maybe I've missed some recent development.  Have I?  I've searched for quite a while to no avail.

Also, as a side, but related question: why is it an error that 2007-01-03 "is before last transaction in portfolio (2014-04-29)" since the former actually is chronologically before the latter date? Am I right to assume that the error is prompted by `quantstrat`'s (actually, I guess it is blotter's) mistaken view that the former is LISTED after the latter in the object?

Comment: Update: I just tried restarting my computer and the above code worked.  While that is interesting, restarting my computer each time I want to run this code is hardly practical.  I've tried using code from [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r) to fix this, but it doesn't help.  (Thanks to #NelsonGon for editing; maybe he can help with links in comments). So I am still looking for help on the substantive matter.

Comment: Another update: after trying this over and over, I've realized I only need to restart R Studio for the code to work.  This is a little more practical than restarting the computer, but any help in understanding how to avoid even this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to update quantstrat and all it's dependencies; blotter, etc.

Comment: #Jared, your suggestion sounds like it might help, but aside from trail and error, is there a way of systematically understanding what packages have what dependencies to insure I cover them all?

Comment: I found [link] (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-dependency-graph.html) as an answer to my question about package dependencies, although -- while interesting -- I'm still not sure what to actually do with it....I'm still restarting RStudio between each run and it's getting old fast.

Comment: It appears that I have having a conversation with myself at this point :) but just in case this will help someone else, I fixed my problem with '.blotter <- new.env()', and 
'.strategy <- new.env()'.

Comment: it's very hard to speculate what the issue here is unless you provide a reproducible example