# How do I solve the "R code execution error" on RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I seem to be getting a continuous error message every time I try to use the console in RStudio.

And this is the error I get:

```
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/Siddhardh/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/StatsBombR/help/StatsBombR.rdb' is corrupt
```

I'm new to R and RStudio.

Comment: Restart R. If that doesn't work, quit RStudio and open it again. This happens sometimes when you update packages mid-session and some component of them, such as documentation, gets rebuilt but I guess not reloaded properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error arises when the package cannot be decompressed by R correctly.

Below can be possible solutions:

1. Try restarting your R session (e.g. `.rs.restartR()` if in RStudio); ([Quit and restart a clean R session from within R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r))
2. Check for possible errors in the creation of the `.Rdb` files which are giving you the errors.
3. The package might have been installed in your computer, even though its does not work or is corrupt, try removing (`?remove.packages()`) it and reinstalling it.

Comment: Thank You. Reinstalling the said package has worked for me.