# Restart R session using R code when not in RStudio?

Tags: r

[`.rs.restartR()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25934774) can be used to restart the R session. But it only seems to work from within RStudio.

When it's run elsewhere:

```
.rs.restartR()
Error in .rs.restartR() : could not find function ".rs.restartR"
```

How can the R session be restarted in other environments? I happen to be operating from a highly constrained cloud environment, so I am limited in what I can do (so things like [<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f10</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33102389)) are out of the question

Comment: In general, functions that begin with `.rs` are functions defined by `RStudio` so they won't be available in general implementations of R. If the R process itself has ended and there is no IDE to work with, you will probably have to use the terminal.