# GGPubr vs. R-Boxplot shows different extreme values

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, boxplot, ggpubr

I used the regular "boxplot" function to check my data for extreme values. For presentations within the project, I then created the same boxplots using the package ggpubr (which builds on ggplot2).

As far I understood the whiskers should represent the same area in both blots. To my surprise, an extreme value appears in the ggpubr boxplot, which is not shown in the r-boxplot.

[**Screenshot ggpubr boxplot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfxqn.png)

[**Screenshot r-boxplot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQmEs.png)

**Code R-Boxplot:**

```
boxplot(data$vtrust_post1, data$vtrust_post2)
```

**Code Ggpubr:**

```
vtrust_a_b_long %>% 
ggboxplot(x = "drive", y = "count", bxp.errorbar = TRUE)
```

**For ggpubr I had to convert the data to long format:**

```
vtrust_a_b <- data.frame("subject_no" = data$id, "a" = data$vtrust_post1, "b" = data$vtrust_post2)

vtrust_a_b_long <- vtrust_a_b %>%
  gather(key = "drive", value = "count", a, b)
```

Did I do something wrong? Both data contain the same maximum value. Could it be that the extreme values are defined differently in r-boxplot and ggpubr/ggplot2?

I am very grateful for your help!

**UPDATE: Code to reproduce the problem**

Using this code it indicates an extremevalue only for the ggpubr version.

```
a <- c(1.50, 3.50, 1.50, 3.00, 1.25, 5.25, 2.50, 2.50, 1.50, 2.25, 1.75, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 4.50, 2.25, 3.25, 1.25, 2.50, 2.75, 1.75, 4.25, 2.75, 2.00,
 1.75, 3.50, 3.25, 3.00, 1.25, 1.25, 3.75, 1.50, 1.75, 2.25, 1.25, 2.00, 1.50, 3.50, 1.75, 3.25)

boxplot(a)
ggpubr::ggboxplot(a)
```

**Update 2**
Because of the hint, it could be caused by local settings within R, I tried the code at https://rdrr.io/snippets/. Again, the discrepancy occurs:

[Screenshot comparison r-base boxplot and ggpubr boxplot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVZu4.png)

Comment: Base R's boxplot should catch outliers at 1.5 x IQR but it looks like it isn't. You could try forcing it by setting range=1.5 as a boxplot argument to see if it makes a difference. If its range is set at zero, the whisker will extend to the data extreme. It's hard to check without your data.

Comment: suggest start R in a new session. There is possibly some global setting that you have changed without knowing. See the code in the answer for demonstration of lack of reproducibility.

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r

Comment: You should probably include the data so people can reproduce your problem. The code won't work without the data.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried both, but it changed nothing. I added a new code to reproduce the problem to the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reviewing the source code for base R [`graphics::boxplot`](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/graphics/R/boxplot.R), line 48 shows that the whiskers are calculated by `grDevices::boxplot.stats`. Reviewing the source code of `boxplot.stats` (by typing it at the prompt) reveals it uses `stats::fivenum` to calculate the distance to plot the whiskers.

```
fivenum(a)
#[1] 1.250 1.625 2.250 3.125 5.250
```

Lines 156 and 157 of the `graphics::boxplot` source shows the whiskers extend from the 2nd value to the 1st value and then from the 4th value to the 5th value.

In contrast, reviewing the source for [`geom_boxplot`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-boxplot.r) shows us that the whiskers extend to the *nearest data point* that is no more than 1.5 times the IQR from the hinges. This is calculated by `stats::quantile`:

```
quantile(a,0.75) + diff(quantile(a,c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))[c(2,4)])*1.5
#5.125
```

Since element 6 of `a` is `5.25`, it is more than `5.125`, and therefore, the whisker does not extend to that point.